# Why event.target gives multiple results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

I have a 3*3 table. When I click on `td` element in my console log `td` is printed six times and I want it to print out just once. Why is this happening and how to prevent it?

JS:

```
$("*").click(function(event){
  console.log(event.target);//is this here executing 6 times, why...
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are attaching the click to all elements and not just the td like this: $("td").click(function(event){console.log(event.target);});?

Comment: other events are bubbling up

Comment: You're probably trying to do something like event delegation. You'd put the handler on the `table` in that case. jQuery has its own means of delegation where you can pass a selector if you use `.on()`, but for simple cases, using `event.target` works too.

Comment: @tabz100 I just want the click to be attached on one element

Comment: @atho, see the first code snippet in my answer. It will only attach to `td` elements

Comment: `$("table").click(function(event){ console.log(event.target); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of **propagation**. Since you used `$('*')` it attached the click handler **seperately** to **each** element. Therefore, when you clicked on `td`, the event *bubbled* up to parent element handlers.

To see the difference, try

```js
$("td").click(function(event){
  console.log(event.target);//will only log once since it was only attached to td
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**or** *stop* propagation

```js
$("*").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log(event.target);//will only log once since propagation was stopped above
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @aw04, right and both snippets will only print the innermost clicked element

Comment: @aw04, I just tested both snippets in my answer and they only print once. I am using chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: both print once on Firefox

Comment: @aw04, try refreshing the page? maybe you dont have my most up to date answer?

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting `*` in your jquery, that means that each and every element in your DOM will be selected by that query. Now, in jQuery the events bubble up the DOM untill the document or body. If you click an element that has 5 grandparents, the event will be executed once for the clicked element, and once for each of the elements parents and so on untill reaching the body. If you dont want this to happen, you should add `event.stopPropagation`.

```
$("*").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log(event.target);//is this here executing 6 times, why...
});
```

Comment: Me neither I believe that it's a correct answer. Maybe not the best, but still correct.

Answer (score 0):

This will also help: http://jsfiddle.net/wek58fk4/1/

```
$("*").click(function(event){
  console.log(event.target);//is this here executing 6 times, why...
  return false;
});
```

Comment: return false is the same as event.preventDefault(). I dont think that this will stop the bubbling effect.

Comment: @taxicala: It does (bizarrely enough) in jQuery but binding to `*` doesn't make sense if you're just going to stop the propagation anyway.

Comment: @taxicala Did you even look at the fiddle an try it. I don't care being downvoted, but this works and it is correct way to do it in jQuery. It's the same as event.preventDefault + event.stopPropagation.

Comment: @squint I agree that binding to everything is weird, but I always try to stay as close as possible to OP's code. I can't judge from here why OP is writing it like that.

Comment: @taxicala No worries dude. But I always appreciate an explanation when people downvote on my answer. I wasn't targeting you ;) in particular

Comment: @Mikey its ok and you where right, I checked it and return false also stops bubbling.